# MUI DataGridPro rowsPerPageOptions dropdown is not visible using custom pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

I am using react

"react": "^18.2.0",

"@mui/material": "^5.10.7",

"@mui/x-data-grid-pro": "^5.16.0"

if I use custom pagination ,rowsPerPageOptions  dropdown is not visible, if I use default pagination then rowsPerPageOptions dropdown is visible. Could you please help me with this.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
 import { DataGridPro,  gridPageCountSelector,
  gridPageSelector,
  useGridApiContext,
  useGridSelector } from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro";
  
import { useDemoData } from "@mui/x-data-grid-generator";
import { Pagination } from "@mui/material";
 
function CustomPagination() {
  const apiRef = useGridApiContext();
  const page = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageSelector);
  const pageCount = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageCountSelector);

  return (
    <Pagination
      color="primary"
      count={pageCount}
      page={page + 1}
      onChange={(event, value) => apiRef.current.setPage(value - 1)}
      variant="outlined"  shape="rounded"
      
      />
  );
}

export default function CustomPaginationGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: "Commodity",
    rowLength: 50,
    maxColumns: 6
  });

  return (
    <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGridPro
        pagination
        pageSize={25}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[25, 50, 100]}
        components={{
          Pagination: CustomPagination
        }}
        {...data}
        checkboxSelection
        disableSelectionOnClick
       
      />
       
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by custom rowsPerPageOptions dropdown, here is the solution.

**CustomPagination.js** file

```
import {
    FormControl, InputLabel,
    MenuItem,
    Pagination,
    Select,
    Typography
} from "@mui/material";

import {
    gridPageCountSelector,
    gridPageSelector,
    useGridApiContext,
    useGridSelector
} from "@mui/x-data-grid-pro";
import * as React from "react";

import { CssBaseline } from "@mui/material";
import { Box } from "@mui/system";

export default function CustomPagination(props) {
    const apiRef = useGridApiContext();
    const cuttentPage = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageSelector);
    const pageCount = useGridSelector(apiRef, gridPageCountSelector);
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(25);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setRowsPerPage(event.target.value);
        apiRef.current.setPageSize(event.target.value)
    };
    React.useEffect(() => {
        apiRef.current.setPageSize(25)
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <CssBaseline />
            <FormControl sx={{ m: 1, p: 0, mt: 1, minWidth: 80 }}>
                <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Rows</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    size="small"
                    labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
                    id="demo-simple-select"
                    label="Rows"
                    value={rowsPerPage}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                >
                    <MenuItem value={25}>25</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={50}>50</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={100}>100</MenuItem>
                    <MenuItem value={200}>200</MenuItem>

                </Select>
            </FormControl>
            <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
            <Pagination
                count={pageCount}
                page={cuttentPage + 1}

                variant="outlined" color="primary" shape="rounded"
                onChange={(event, value) => apiRef.current.setPage(value - 1)}
            />
        </>

    );
}
```

and mui datagrid

```
const [pageSize, setPageSize] = React.useState(25);
const [pageNo, setPageNo] = React.useState(0);
const pagechangeCalled = (number) => {
    setPageNo(number)
 }

<Box sx={{ height: 600, minWidth: "100%" }}>
              <DataGridPro
                rows={data}
                getRowId={(row) => row.ticsNumber}
                columns={myincidentsColumns}
                onRowDoubleClick={(ids) => someFunction(ids)}
                onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
                density="compact"
                pagination
                onPageChange={pagechangeCalled}
                components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar, Pagination: CustomPagination }}
                componentsProps={{
                  toolbar: {
                    showQuickFilter: true,
                    quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 500 },
                   
                  },
                }}
               
              />
```

[image]